# how to derive values ​from foreign key field? django

Tags: django

model.py

```
class Authors(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Books(models.Model):
  date_pub = models.DateField()
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  author = models.ForeignKey('Authors')
```

I need to derive the names of authors from a foreign key, but the `Books.objects.all().values_list('author', 'name')` command infers the id from the `Authors` model. how to derive author names from the `Books` model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Books.objects.all().values_list('author__name')
```

It is mentioned clearly in Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list